# How to use a process already running in tasklist

Tags: windows, command, instance, tasklist

Under Windows 7, I need to run a file, say "file_name", with myapp.exe through a command line. When I call myapp and file_name with their full paths, it opens a new instance of myapp (it is not single-instanced). Is it at all possible to use a running instance of myapp, if there is one (as if I just dragged and dropped file_name into myapp's window) ?

I know how to check if myapp.exe is already running using tasklist. But in case there is a running instance, I don't know I can get some kind of application handle through which I can call file_name, without opening a new myapp.exe.

Thanks!